# Is a batch operation to save a set of navigation properties possible?

Tags: json, odata, batch-processing, wcf-data-services

For example: Company has Employees.
By posting to odata.svc/Company(1)/Employees/$ref, I can save Company-Employee relation. Can I save multiple Company-Employee links this way using odata.svc/Company(1)/Employees/$ref/$batch ?
I tried but didnt work. If this is incorrect way, is there any other alternative ?

Answer (score 0):

OData does support batching, I'm not sure what version of OData you are using but here is some documentation from v3 (v4 is the same) http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/batch-processing/

In your example batch URL, you are adding $batch to the end of the URL that you are using, instead you have to POST to [odata.svc/$batch](http://odata.svc/$batch) with a request that contains details of all of the operations that you want to perform. For example, here is one of the request taken from that link:

> POST /service/$batch HTTP/1.1  Host: host  Content-Type:
>   multipart/mixed; boundary=batch_36522ad7-fc75-4b56-8c71-56071383e77b
>
> --batch_36522ad7-fc75-4b56-8c71-56071383e77b  Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
>   boundary=changeset_77162fcd-b8da-41ac-a9f8-9357efbbd621 
>   Content-Length: ###
>
> --changeset_77162fcd-b8da-41ac-a9f8-9357efbbd621 Content-Type: application/http  Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary  Content-ID: 1
>
> POST /service/Customers HTTP/1.1  Host: host   Content-Type:
>   application/atom+xml;type=entry  Content-Length: ###
>
> --changeset_77162fcd-b8da-41ac-a9f8-9357efbbd621 Content-Type: application/http  Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
>
> POST $1/Orders HTTP/1.1  Host: host  Content-Type:
>   application/atom+xml;type=entry  Content-Length: ###
>
> --changeset_77162fcd-b8da-41ac-a9f8-9357efbbd621-- 
>   --batch_36522ad7-fc75-4b56-8c71-56071383e77b--